# Permission error when saving to documentDirectory

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I am trying to save favourites to document directory, the code works fine when I run it in simulator however when I build it to my device I am getting the following error.

> You don’t have permission to save the file
> “Documents.LikedDepartments” in the folder
> “F36073C0-AC1E-46CA-BC1E-E03F9F316E1D”.

Also it might be worth noting that when I change use `.cachesDirectory` instead of `.documentDirectory` it works fine.

How can I grant write access for the documents directory ?

```
import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    static var documentsDirectory: URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        print(paths)
        return paths[0]
    }
}
```

```
let savePath = FileManager.documentsDirectory.appendingPathExtension("LikedDepartments")

func save() {
    let favourites = calculateFavourites()
    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(favourites)
        try data.write(to:savePath, options: [.atomic, .completeFileProtection])
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool file extension `.LikedDepartments`

Use `appendingPathComponent` instead.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1417069-appendingpathcomponent

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity: do you have an idea how come did this work for cachesDirectory ?

Comment: I don’t know. Allowing people write access to root of caches isn’t bad but is bad for documents is my random guess.